# independent question

Tags: probability

If we have pdf f(x) and f(y) and they are independent

f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)

Question

In this case, cumulative function of f(x) and f(y) (F(x) and F(y)

is F(x,y) = F(x)F(y) always correct?

Comment: Can you try to check yourself, since CDF's are defined as probabilities (namely, $F_X(t)=\Pr[X \leq t]$, etc.)? This should be easy to do, and should give you some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the result about the pdfs ($f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$), then you can prove what you are asking.

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X\le x, Y\le y) = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f_{X,Y}(x,y) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy} = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(x) \mathop{dx} \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(y) \mathop{dy} = F_X(x) F_Y(y).$$

Answer (score 3):

According to the definition, Yes, they should be.
Jointly-distributed random variables X and Y are independent if their joint
cdf is the product of the marginal cdf’s: $$F(X,Y)=F_X(x)F_Y(y)$$For continous variables this is equivalent to the joint pdf being the product of the marginal
pdf’s:$$f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}F_{X,Y}(x,y) =&~ \int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^y f_{X,Y}(s,t)\operatorname d t\operatorname ds \\[2ex] F_X(x)F_Y(y) =&~ \left(\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(s)\operatorname d s\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^y f_{Y}(t)\operatorname d t\right)\end{align}$$

Are these equal?

---

> They should be.   Generally if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $~\mathsf P(X\in\mathcal A, Y\in\mathcal B)=\mathsf P(X\in\mathcal A)~\mathsf P(Y\in \mathcal B)~$ for all sets $\mathcal A, \mathcal B ~\subseteq \Bbb R$ .